# Is affine GIT quotient necessarily an open map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $k$ be a field, $X=$Spec$A$ be an affine scheme with A a f.g. $k$-algebra. $G=$Spec$R$ is a linearly reductive group acting rationally on A. (i.e. every element of $A$ is contained in a finite dimensional $G$-invariant linear subspace of $A$.) By Nagata's theorem, $A^G$ is a f.g. $k$-algebra. We have the affine GIT quotiont $X \rightarrow X//G :=$Spec$A^G$ induced by the inclusion $A^G \rightarrow A$ of $k$-algebras.

Question: is the affine GIT quotient, viewed as a map of the underlying topological spaces, necessarily an open map? (it doesn't need to be an open immersion of schemes.) If not, any counterexample?

Comment: An excellent answer is here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/242048/43639.

Answer (score 1):

I know a ridiculous counterexample. $R= \mathbb{k} [x, y] / (xy=0)$. Consider the action of $G=\mathbb{G}_m$ given by $(x, y) \rightarrow (tx, y)$. Then $R^G = \mathbb{k}[y]$. Consider $U = \{ x \neq 0 \}$. It is an open subset, but the image is $\{  y=0 \}$ (not open).

Comment: But I still want to know for the case of irreducible $X$. I have asked it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837503/is-quotient-of-open-invariant-subset-open but still get no reply =(