# Is quotient of open invariant subset open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-groups

I am reading GIT book by Mumford. He needs special cases of the following conjecture several times.

> **Conjecture** Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group acting on an irreducible affine scheme $X=Spec A$. Let $Y = Spec A^G$ and $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ is canonical map. Let $U$ be an open invariant subset in $X$. Then $\phi (U)$ is open.

**Question** Is it true?

*Remark 1.* It is a theorem from Mumford’s book that $\phi$ is a [categorical quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_quotient).

*Remark 2* As far as Mumford do not formulate the conjecture as a proposition in his book, I expect it to be false.

**Edited** My question is closely related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774158/is-affine-git-quotient-necessarily-an-open-map?rq=1). user31480 has asked about invariant subsets, I have asked about any. I have just realized, that it is not essential at all. For any open subset $U$ one can consider union of $gU$ for all $g \in G$ (still open, has the same image by quotient map, but invariant).

Also I noticed that assumption of $X$ being irreducible is crucial. You can find a counterexample as an answer for aforementioned question.

Comment: If $\pi:X\rightarrow X/G$ is a geometric quotient, then $\pi$ is open. As for existence of geometric quotients c.f: https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/notes_luminy.pdf proposition 1.26

Comment: An excellent answer is here: http://mathoverflow.net/a/242048/43639.